# Add functionality to home button?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, buttons

What application will let me allot a certain functionality to the home button? Currently, I want to make it so that pressing the Home button twice will activate Voice Actions. Do you know of any app that does that?

I'm rooted.

**EDIT:**
Okay, while doing some further research, I found out that one of the ways to achieve this is via a launcher app. I'm currently using ADW Launcher Ex. Is that modifiable via theme to do something like such?

Comment: doubtful. The system was built specifically to disallow applications from doing anything with the Home button. Even with a launcher app I don't think you could get it to recognize a double tap very easily / consistently. If your device has a camera button that is much easier for applications to add functionality to.

Comment: What about rooting does that change anything because that app has some really bad reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app in the Google Play Store called [Advanced Home Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crazyricky.advhomebutton). Although this app won't allow you to directly configure Home button's single press, this may allow you to replace the double-tap which is configurable.

However, this app does mean replacing your default launcher (in your case, ADW launcher). You, may, though, try it out whatsoever and see if it helps your issue.

**Edit:** There have been  **many negative responses** on the app saying the app causes issues with the home button. So you need to be careful while installing such an app.

Comment: Seems to be the closest around.